# render SQL in Rmarkdown notebook, not just when knit

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

If I have an R block in an Rmarkdown notebook, the code is visible in the rendered `nb.html` file. However, if I have a SQL block, I can't find a way to make the code visible in the rendered file.

However, if I generate an `html_document` (standard knitr) instead of an `html_notebook`, the rendered HTML *does* include the SQL code (and output).

Is there a way to get the notebook output to do something closer to what the knit output does?

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered this recently, Harlan, and began by asking if there's a way to get notebook output more like knit output.

I then wondered if there was a way to get knit output more like notebook output and realised that there was.

After asking the folks at RStudio, I learnt that you can add the following line to the YAML options in order to generate a html_document that, when rendered, enables the RMD to be downloaded. Specifically, use:

```
output:
  html_document:
    code_download: true
```

I now use that in all of my code and it works well. I hope it helps you, too.

Comment: Great point, upvoted, but not the solution to the specific problem, alas...!